# Is storing an object literal inside immutable a valid pattern...?

Tags: immutability, immutable.js

so I have Immutable.js in the form of:

`let o = immutable.Map({a: {b: 1}})`

and so my question is, would it be valid to do:

`o.get('a').b = 2`

which will return just the value set, but not a new reference... :/

or other patterns recommended to modidy the internal state of an object literal inside the Immutable map?

I would appreciate if someone can expand on the pattern (if one even exists) of mixing immuatble.js with object literals and recommendations...

tx as always,

Sean.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption that the inner object literal is mutable. You can test this as:

```
var o = immutable.Map({a: {b: 1}})
o.get('a').b = 2;
// b will now be mutated in o;
```

If you would like to create a fully immutable object use the fromJS method provided with Immutable, which will do a deep conversion, or set the value of a to also be a Map.

Edited to add: Regarding appropriate patterns, I recommend going fully immutable as it maintains the contract that any inner objects/array are also immutable.